# Google AMP: Call Tracking dynamic numbers

Tags: amp-html

We have a page using Google's AMP tool.

On the non-amp pages, we're using Google Call Tracking to replace a number on the website with a tracking number

In the body, we set `<body onload="_googWcmGet('number', '{{phone}}')">`

We have many offices, so when someone navigates to "San Diego" for instance, the phone variable will change. Currently, we have 45 offices that we currently track. So the number will automatically change to a specific google tracking phone number depending on what `{{phone}}` renders on the front-end.

Getting back to AMP, I see they have a script: https://amp.dev/documentation/examples/components/amp-call-tracking/

They provide short examples showing that you have to set `config` to a JSON file with contents like:

```
{
  "phoneNumber": "15559876543",
  "formattedPhoneNumber": "1 (555) 987-6543"
}
```

And then you simply wrap the `<a>` in the `amp-call-tracking` tag like so:

```
<amp-call-tracking config="https://amp.dev/static/samples/json/call-tracking-number.json">
  <a href="tel:10001111111">1 (000) 111-1111</a>
</amp-call-tracking>
```

This is all well and good, but how can I get this to function like the example above? I need to be able to use a different number of Call Tracking Numbers depending on what page the user is on and what phone number is originally being displayed.

This is a very static solution Google is providing

Comment: Where does `{{phone}}` come from? Is this server-side rendered? If yes, you should use the same approach to inject the phone number into your AMP pages.

Comment: Each location entry has a field for Phone, so depending on which location page the user is on, the `{{phone}}` variable will reflect that. But that's not my question. The phone is being replaced by a single static number in the JSON. It isn't using Google Call Tracking to determine what number should be used to replace